# Filter large dataframe by two columns using second dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

full.df<-tibble(x = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 5.6, 7.4),
                y = c(4.5, 4.3, 2.6, 5.6, 7.6),
                a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                b = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
```

And a second dataframe that's essentially a subset of `full.df` but missing columns `a` & `b`:

```
subset.df<-tibble(x = c(1.5, 3.5, 7.4), 
                  y = c(4.5, 2.6, 7.6))
```

How can I filter `full.df` on `x` & `y` using `x` & `y` from `subset.df`? I wish to return this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      x     y     a     b
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   1.5   4.5     1     5
2   3.5   2.6     3     7
3   7.4   7.6     5     9
```

I have tried `full.df %>% filter(x == subset.df$x & y == subset.df$y)` but this only returns the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
full.df %>% right_join(subset.df, by = c('x','y'))
```

Comment: Is this homework?!

Comment: Wow, my brain really isn't working today. Can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: Ha, no. It's for a paper I'm working on, if you can believe it. I just got stuck down the `filter` route and didn't even consider `join`.

Comment: Fair enough! The less elegant filter approach would be `filter(full.df, paste(x,y) %in% paste(subset.df$x, subset.df$y))`

Comment: I've been sat here for like 20 mins thinking filter, filter, filter. I use joins frequently so I'm baffled as to why I didn't think of it. I've been working too much recently,  I think my brain is turning to mush.

Comment: Stretch your legs and have a cuppa!